# How reduceLeft works on sequence of Functions returning Future

Tags: scala

This might be a naive question and I am sorry for that. I am studying Scala Futures and stumbled on below code:

```
object Main extends App {
    def await[T](f: Future[T]) = Await.result(f, 10.seconds)

    def f(n: Int): Future[Int] = Future {n + 1}
    def g(n: Int): Future[Int] = Future {n * 2}
    def h(n: Int): Future[Int] = Future {n - 1}

    def doAllInOrder[T](f: (T => Future[T])*): T => Future[T] = {
      f.reduceLeft((a,b) => x => a(x).flatMap(y => b(y)))
    }

    println(await(doAllInOrder(f, g, h)(10))) // 21
  }
```

I know how `reduceLeft` works when it is applied on `Collections`. But in the above example, as I understand, in the first pass of `reduceLeft` value `x` i.e. `10` is applied to Function `a` and the result is applied to Function `b` using `flatMap` which eventually return `Future[Int]` (say, I call it `result`). In the next pass of `reduceLeft` the `result` and Function `h` has to be used, but here is I am troubled.

The `result` is actually an already executed Future, but the `reduceLeft` next pass expects a Function which returns a Future[Int].Then how it is working?

Another thing I am not able to understand how each pass sending its result to next pass of `reduceLeft`, i.e. how `x` is getting it's value in subsequent passes.

Though both of my confusions are interrelated and a good explanation may help clear my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think about `reduceLeft` to be independent from `Future` execution. `reduceLeft` creates a new function by combining two given ones and that's it.

`reduceLeft` is applied to a `Seq` of `T => Future[T]`. So, it's just simple iteration from left to right over sequence of functions taking first and second elements and reducing it to one single value, reducing this value with the 3rd element and so on. Eventually, having just two element left that are reduced to a single one.

The result of `reduceLeft` has to be of the same type as the type of elements in the collection. In your case, it's function `T => Future[T]`.

Let's understand what `(a,b) => x => a(x).flatMap(y => b(y))` is doing

This means the following. Given functions `a` and `b`, create a function that combines function `a` with `b`. Mathematically it's `c(x)=b(a(x))`.

Now, `a` and `b` are functions returning futures. And futures can be chained with the help of `map`/`flatMap` methods.

You should read `x => a(x).flatMap(y => b(y))` as

> Given an input `x`, apply function `a(x)`, this results in a `Future`,  when this future is completed, take result `y` and apply function `b(y)`, this results in a new `Future`. This is the result of function `c`.

Note: value x is Int at all times. It is the input parameter for your new reduced function.

If it's still not clear, let's address the points of confusions

> The result is actually an already executed Future.

No future is guaranteed to be executed at any point here. `map` and `flatMap` are non blocking operation and it applies functions to a Future. The result of this application is still a `Future`.

> Another thing I am not able to understand how each pass sending its
>   result to next pass of reduceLeft, i.e. how x is getting it's value in
>   subsequent passes.

This is easier to understand when just having integers in a collection. Given following code

```
Seq(1, 2, 5, 10).reduceLeft(_ - _)
```

It will take `1`, `2` and apply `-` function, this will result in `-1`. It will then combine `-1` and `5` resulting in `-6`. And finally, `-6` with `10` resulting in `-16`.

Comment: In the pass 2 of reduceLeft, the result of Function 'c' to be used as argument 'a', but the value of argument 'a' now is not a function rather a Future which eventually will complete. So how can I compose c(x)=b(a(x)) in 2nd pass.

Further if result of 'c' is the value for argument 'a', then from where the value for 'x' is obtained?

Comment: There is no difference between 1st and 2nd. You have two functions `f` and `g` that can be reduced into a new function `c` that is of the same type `Int => Future[Int]` (or 1st redeceLeft applcation). Now, we can reduce `c` with `h`  (which have the same type) into a final function

Comment: Ok, understood, but what about value of 'x' in subsequent pass...

Comment: value x is `Int` at all times. It is the input parameter for your new reduced function. It will be provided when Future is eventually completed and final function `F(x) = h(g(f(x)))` is applied at this time

Comment: you have to think about reduceLeft to be independent from Future execution. RedeceLeft creates a new function by combining two given ones and that's it.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, Thanks a lot.